# Recuperar id en comboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo la siguiente función para llenar un comboBox con los datos ingresados en el formulario por el usuario, esto funciona correctamente.

```
def onTextChanged(self, text):
    if text:
  sql = ("SELECT sec.Nombre as Seccion,sec,idSeccion FROM [Lote] lot \
            inner join [Seccion] sec on sec.idInforme = lot.idInforme \
                Where idLote = '%s'") % \
              (self.dlg.lote.text())
        cursorLista.execute(sql)
        self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItems([str(x[0]) for x in cursorLista])
```

Luego lo llamo desde

```
self.dlg.lote.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
result = self.dlg.exec_()
```

El problema es que ahora necesito obtener el id se la Seccion que se selecciono en el comboBox y guardarlo en una variable , como puedo obtenerlo ya que en el query estoy trayendo todos los idSeccion para ese Lote.

Comment: ¿tú quieres obtener el texto seleccionado en el combobox?

Comment: El texto del comboBox tiene el nombre de la seccion, de esa lista se selecciona una, necesito recuperar el idSeccion en una variable

Comment: ¿en `cursorLista` esta esa información?

Comment: En un combobox solo puedes añadir QStrings así que te toca hacer algo como `self.dlg.comboBox.addItems([str(x[0]) + "(ID: "+str(x[1])+")" for x in cursorLista])`. Esto complica que luego para capturar los datos al seleccionar cualquier objeto del Combobox tienes que partir la información en "Seleccion, seccion", pero es la única manera de añadir digamos... "columnas" a un combobox.

Comment: Si, correctamente

Comment: ¿x[1] es el idSeccion?

Comment: x[1] tiene el idSeccion que necesito almacenar en una variable, pero solo el de la seccion que se selecciono en el comboBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QComboBox permite almacenar informacion adicional asociada a cada item usando `setItemData()`, en tu caso podrias hacer el idSection, y recuperarlo mediante `itemData()`:

```
def onTextChanged(self, text):
    if text:
        sql = ("SELECT sec.Nombre as Seccion,sec,idSeccion FROM [Lote] lot \
            inner join [Seccion] sec on sec.idInforme = lot.idInforme \
                Where idLote = '%s'") % \
              (self.dlg.lote.text())
        cursorLista.execute(sql)
        self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
        for i, x in enumerate(cursorLista):
            self.dlg.comboBox.addItem(str(x[0]))
            self.dlg.comboBox.setItemData(i, x[1])

    ...
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        ix = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
        idSection = self.dlg.comboBox.itemData(ix)
```